# Question regarding applications of formally verified software: CS or CSTHEORY?

Tags: discussion

I have a specific question that in as a summary, or in broad terms, I would describe as "about the application of formally verified software".

Does this fit better in cstheory (this site) or in CS (computer science)?

I am not sure, because on the one hand formally verified software fits more in CSTHEORY, but applications would more fit in CS (computer science).

Comment: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/2662/

Comment: The main distinction between cstheory and cs is not theory vs. applied, but research level vs. not research level. In fact, we even have an [application-of-theory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-of-theory) tag. Do you believe your question is research level? Or do you suspect an undergraduate textbook would answer it? If it is the latter then I recommend CS.SE

Answer (score 1):

Based on the guidelines in the question Kaveh links to, I think it's quite possible to pose a question that's on-scope for this site. It would probably end up being a big-list/CW question though.